# I'm unable to connect Docker Remote API using nodejs hosted in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, remoteapi

I have created t1.micro instance in Amazon web-services(AWS), and installed docker.io.
I executed following commend in SSH client "sudo docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d &".

when I am trying to get all images : myipaddres:4243/images/json.
I'am getting "This webpage is not available" page.

Comment: Just to be sure. You opened 4243 tcp port in AWS security group?

Comment: @odk Yes, I opened 4243, 80 ports

Comment: And when you run `curl 127.0.0.1:4243/images/json` on this amazon instance it works? If yes then it's for sure problem with firewall or wrong ip used as `myipaddres`.

Comment: if you have any **Docker remote api** tutorial please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found https://github.com/crosbymichael/dockerui expose remote api on my host. :)

Comment: Could you add more information about that? As in, what exactly you did? And if dockerui has changed much, could you tell how to do that with the current dockerui?